# Meu projeto Spring Data Hibernate não cria as tabelas no SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring

estou estudando Spring Data com hibernate e estou usando o banco de dados SQL server. Montei o projeto, com as dependências no arquivo pom. O projeto é complicado sem erros, porém, não cria as tabelas no banco de dados SQL Server. Já revisei todo o código inúmeras vezes, refiz o projeto varias vezes e esbarro no mesmo problema. Alguém consegue me ajudar no que estou fazendo de errado ou que está faltando no meu projeto para eu conseguir criar as tabelas?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>projeto-spring-data-aula</groupId>
  <artifactId>projeto-spring-data-aula</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>projeto-spring-data-aula</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.2.jre13</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.18.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.18.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
   
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.4</version>
   </dependency>
   
      <dependency>
         <groupId>log4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.16</version>
      </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

UsuarioSpringData.java

```
package projeto.spring.data.aula.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UsuarioSpringData {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    private String login;
    
    private String senha;
    
    private String nome;
    
    private String email;
    
    private int idade;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="projeto-spring-data-aula">
        <class>projeto.spring.data.aula.model.UsuarioSpringData</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

spring-config.xml está dentro da pasta META_INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="projeto.spring.data.aula.model" />


     <!-- Define a conexao com o banco de dados -->
     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
         <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
         <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=spring-data-teste-aula"/>
         <property name="username" value="sa"/>
         <property name="password" value="masterkey"/>
     </bean>
     
     
     <!-- Define as configurações do JPA -->
     
     <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
               <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER"/>
               <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/> <!-- Gerar as tabelas no banco -->
            </bean>
      </property>
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="projeto-spring-data-aula"/>
     </bean>
     
     <!-- Ativa o controle transacional -->
     
     <bean id="transactionManager"
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" scope="singleton">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />     
     </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="projeto.spring.data.aula.dao" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua tabela `UsuarioSpringData` deve possuir a anotação a qual tabela se refere

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MINHATABELA")
```